# Jasper Reports empty PDF report problem, using Spring ModelAndView

Tags: spring, pdf, jasper-reports, ireport

I am trying to generate PDF report with Jasper Reports using Spring. But report is always empty. I searched a lot and could not find problem. I tried to write byte[] pdfReport to OutputStream but result is same, report is always empty.

I have 2 parameters one o them is testName and one of them is chart. Both can not display at pdf report.

Thanks a lot for your help,

Here is the code that generates report.

```
//My class extends MultiActionController

DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();

dataset.setValue(String.format("%s, %s", "pie1", "pie1"),20);
dataset.setValue(String.format("%s, %s", "pie2", "pie2"),80);

JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("testPie", dataset, true, true, false);

Map model = new HashMap(); 
model.put("chart", chart.createBufferedImage(200, 200)); 
model.put("testName", "test report");
model.put("format", "pdf");

AbstractJasperReportsView  view = new JasperReportsMultiFormatView();
view.setUrl("/WEB-INF/classes/reports/"+"test1"+".jasper");
view.setApplicationContext(getApplicationContext());
view.setContentType("application/pdf");

Properties header = new Properties();
view.setHeaders(header);

ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(view, model);

JasperReport report =  (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/classes/reports/"+"test1"+".jasper"));

JasperPrint prt = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, model);
byte[] pdfReport = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(prt);

return mv;
```

And here is jrxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test1" language="groovy" pageWidth="700" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="660" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="2"/>
    <parameter name="testName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="chart" class="java.awt.Image" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="48" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="14" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="229" splitType="Stretch">
            <image>
                <reportElement x="162" y="13" width="200" height="200"/>
                <imageExpression class="java.awt.Image"><![CDATA[$P{chart}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="37" y="61" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{testName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="112" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="76" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you doing the following?

```
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(view, model);

JasperReport report =  (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/classes/reports/"+"test1"+".jasper"));

JasperPrint prt = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, model);
byte[] pdfReport = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(prt);

return mv;
```

Using JasperReportsMultiFormatView() already combines the filling and exporting of the report. No need for the following:

```
JasperReport report =  (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/classes/reports/"+"test1"+".jasper"));

JasperPrint prt = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, model);
byte[] pdfReport = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(prt);
```

You must declare the JRXML file and report data key in a resource bundle.

I suggest you check this guide I wrote for **Spring 3 MVC - Jasper Integration Tutorial:**
http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-3-mvc-jasper-integration.html

Just modify the views to use the JasperReportsMultiFormatView() instead.

Check the Tutorials section for more. If I have time later, I'm gonna make a tutorial using JasperReportsMultiFormatView(). If not maybe tomorrow. Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I removed the unnecessary code but result is same, pdf is empty. And i am sorry i dont know about report data key must be declared in a resource bundle. I just generate the jrxml file with iReports then compile it with Maven and use it. could you please tell more about the report data key? and your tutorials are very helpful, i will keep reading them.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you post here how you declare the new code and the resource bundle? When you generate the JRXML file from iReports, you'll have to edit something there manually

Comment: I've added a tutorial using JasperReportsMultiFormatView at http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-mvc-3-jasper-how-to-use.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a property in jasper report called 'whenNoDataType'. Did you tried setting that to 
whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail"

Also the report language is given as 'groovy'. Why?

Comment: If you use iReport by default it uses Groovy. You have to manually change it. I believe it would be better if it's blank or at least prompts us to choose a language